# How to add a value to an existing value in php

Tags: php

Consider my variable `$result` to be `01212`.... Now if i add `1` to my variable i get the answer `1213`,but i want it to be `01213`.... My php code is

```
echo sprintf('%02u', ($result+1));
```

**Edit:**

Answers to this question works.. But what happens if my variable is `$result` to be `0121212`
in future...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `%05u` instead on `%02u`

```
echo sprintf('%05u', ($result+1));
```

**EDIT:**

To generalize it:

```
<?php

$result = "0121211";

$len = strlen($result+1) + 1;

printf("%0${len}d", ($result+1)); // print 0121212


?>
```

Comment: @codaaddict what happens if my variable becomes 0121212... Will your syntax work for this

Comment: Oh..seems like you want a generalized solution..I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

you could try:

```
str_pad($result, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: -1 one for complicated solution, +1 for introducing me to str_pad :]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something here but it could be as simple as

```
$result = '0'. ($result+1);
```

edit:

```
$test = array('01212', '0121212', '012121212121212', '-01212');
foreach( $test as $result ) {
  $result = '0'.($result+1);
  echo $result, "\n";
}
```

prints

```
01213
0121213
012121212121213
0-1211
```

( you see, there are limitations ;-) )

Comment: maybe with a `strval` will be better:
`echo '0'.strval($result+1);`

Comment: strval() or implicit cast to string ...what's the difference here? And in case you want to avoid any implicit cast `$result = '0' . strval(intval($result)+1);` would be more consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Read here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

in sprintf, you also has to specify length you want - so in your case, if you want any number to be shown 5chars long, you haveto write

```
echo sprintf ('%05d', $d); // 5 places taking decimal
```

or even better

```
printf ('%05d', $d);
```

Comment: @Adam what happens if my variable becomes 0121212... Will your syntax work for this...

Comment: then you simply use `%07d` isntead of `%05d` - you have to tell printf/sprintf how many palces should your numbers take - it can't do it for you.

Comment: alsou you can swap `d` for `u` - complete list of possible values for type of variable `printf`-ed, go to that link I posted :]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to have a '0' in front of the number, so here would be the simplest :P

```
echo '0'. $result;
```

Or if you insist on using `sprintf`:

```
$newresult = $result + 1;
echo sprintf('%0'.(strlen(strval($newresult))+1).'u', $newresult);
```